# Use .gitignore to find if any files are cached in git

Tags: git, awk, gitignore

My team is using Visual Studio and they accidentally pushed everything without using a .gitignore. I now have the .gitignore in place, however, files are stilled stored in the git cache. So I want to search my directory to find these files

I am imagining doing this with something like

`awk '/$/ {print $1} .gitignore | xargs git rm'`

or, since I obviously don't want to test this by deleting everything, something safer like this

`awk '/$/ {print $1} .gitignore | xargs find -iname'`

but I'm slightly off. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`git ls-files` is your friend here.

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -ic \
| xargs git rm --cached
```

@aurelianus's answer is simpler and so that much better if unstaged changes aren't a concern.